# basichttpclient execute throws "SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated" why?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, httpclient

I know related questions are asked in other places but mine is different :)

I'm using BasicHttpClient and a HttpPoster to send stuff to a thirdparty service. I'm using this in a scenario where i have JMS listeners using a single bean to post stuff. I didn't think this was a problem since the BasicHttpclient uses SingleClientConnectionManager and the javadoc says

```
This connection manager maintains only one active connection at a time. Even though this class is thread-safe it ought to be used by one execution thread only.
```

(*thread-safe* is key here) But, when i have two simultaneous requests i get the classic

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
```

Why do i get that? I don't clean up anything since the basicclient does that according to the docs.

my bean constructor:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, SMS_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
params.setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, SMS_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_CONTENT_CHARSET,
            encoding);
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.HTTP_ELEMENT_CHARSET,
            encoding);
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

poster = new HttpPost(mtUrl);
poster.setHeader("Content-type", contentType);

responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
```

my code to run a post call:

```
public String[] sendMessage(MtMessage mess) throws MtSendException, MtHandlingException {

    StringEntity input;

    try {
        String postBody = assembleMessagePostBody(mess);
        input = new StringEntity(postBody);
        poster.setEntity(input);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpclient.execute(poster, responseHandler);
        return new String[]{extractResponseMessageId(response)};
    } catch(HttpResponseException ee){
        throw new MtSendException(ee.getStatusCode(), ee.getMessage(), false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new MtSendException(0, e.getMessage(), false);
    } finally{

    }
}
```

I thought that although the "sendMessage" could be called from multiple JMS listener threads at once, it would be thread safe, since the connectionhandler is thread safe. I guess i could just make the sendMessage() method synchronized perhaps.

If anyone has any input, i'd be most thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SingleClientConnectionManager` is fully thread safe in the sense that when used by multiple execution threads its internal state is synchronized and is always consistent. This does not change the fact that it can dispense a single connection only. So, if two threads attempt to lease a connection, only one can succeed, while the other is likely to get 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager'

You should be using a pooling connection manager if your application needs to execute requests concurrently.

Comment: Right. With synchronized, i would have expected thread#2 to wait for the lock from thread#1, not the API to throw an exception, i.e. that thread2 can execute its http request once thread 1 is finished. Thanks for clarifying, guess i'll see what pooling ones are there.